# computing JavaFX animation values without knowing layout

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

As succinctly as I can manage: Given that I need the layout information of a node (the actual height/width of a node as rendered) to compute my animation, how can I get that information before javafx draws a frame with it?

A little bit longer explanation:

I've got a TreeItem that has child items appearing in it (at the front). What I'd like to have is an animation to cause all existing children to slide down to make room for the new item which would slide in. Each child tree-items contents are different and only known at run-time, meaning the height of each child tree item cannot be expressed as a constant.

This got me writing code along these lines:

```
groupController.groupTreeItem.getChildren().addListener(
        new ListChangeListener<TreeItem<Node>>() {
            @Override public void onChanged(Change<? extends TreeItem<Node>> c) {
                while(c.next()){
                    if ( ! c.wasAdded()){
                        continue;
                    }

                    TreeItem newItem = c.getAddedSublist().get(0)

                    new Timeline(
                        new KeyFrame(
                            seconds(0), 
                            new KeyValue(view.translateYProperty(), -1 * newItem.getHeight())
                        ),
                        new KeyFrame(
                            seconds(1),
                            new KeyValue(view.translateYProperty(), 0)
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
);
```

the issue here is that as when a treeItem is added to another, its components aren't laid out by the time the invalidation event is fired, meaning `newItem.view.getHeight()` returns 0.

My next thought was to then have the animation performed as a reaction to both a change in the list content and a sequential change to the height property, (which got me to write some really hideous code that I'd rather not share --listeners adding listeners is not something I really want to write). This almost works, except that javaFX will draw a single frame with the height property set but without the animations translation applied. I could hack down this road further and try to work something out with opacity being toggled and jobs being enqueued for later, but I figured that this would be the path to madness.

I'm wondering if there's some pseudo-class foo or some clever use of a layout property I could use to help me here. I've been poking around at various combinations of various properties, and haven't gotten anywhere. It seems that as soon as the component has a height, it is rendered, regardless of any listeners you put in or around that height assignment.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: One thing I usually do in this situation is to 'quietly' render the object somewhere the user can't see, and once it's finished rendering, then I obtain the properties, which allows for the proper animation to continue. you might be able to also attach a listener to your stage `.setOnShown()`, I believe, and then handle your animations inside of that listener, since it'll gaurantee to be shown. You might see some strange artifacting-type things happen with that possibly, however. Although I doubt it

Comment: ahh thats very clever. Its a bit of a hack but I cant see how it would cause problems, unless the hidden component somehow lays out the node differently than the actual screen would, and that shouldn't be too hard to avoid. I will try this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Similar to Will, sometimes I'll add a sceneProperty invalidation listener to the node, run a check if (getScene() != null){logic}    mostly when using default methods in interfaces. I think your situation might benefit from some default values as well...

Answer (score 0):

have you tried, overriding this

```
@Override
protected void updateBounds() {
    super.updateBounds();
}
```

Comment: Well thats interesting, on the `Node` base class thats an internal method, meaning I wouldn't have access to overwrite it, but the common subclasses of node (Pane, Region, etc) all raise its visibility to protected, which means we _can_ override it. Ill give this a shot.